# Validate int value depending on other int values

Tags: c#, validation, c#-4.0

I have 4 variables (int values):

```
int adults = 0;
int child = 0;
int singleMoto = 0;
int doubleMoto = 0;
```

The rules are the following:

`singleMoto` is a Motorcycle where only 1 adult can ride.
`doubleMoto` is a Motorcycle where only 2 adults or 1 adult with 1 child can ride.

So if I have:

```
adults = 3;
child = 0;
singleMoto = 2;
doubleMoto = 1;
```

The above validation is **FALSE** because:

> 3 Adults and 0 Child configuration is  3 `singleMoto` **OR** 1 `singleMoto` and 1 `doubleMoto`

Other example could be:

```
adults = 5;
child = 1;
singleMoto = 4;
doubleMoto = 1;
```

The above validation is **TRUE** because:

> 5 Adults and 1 Child configuration:
>
> > 4 `singleMoto` **AND**  1 `doubleMoto`
> >
> > 2 `singleMoto` **AND** 2 `doubleMoto`

Right now Im validating this using simple `IF` statement like:

```
if(adults == 3 and child == 0){
   // show validation
}
```

But Im sure this could done using MOD % or something.

Any clue?

Comment: If your first statement is correct (3, 0, 2, 1) = false then you should probably add that you want to only allow the least number of vacant seats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking:

```
public static bool Validate(int adults, int children, int singleMoto, int doubleMoto)
    {
        var childSeats = doubleMoto;
        var adultSeats = doubleMoto * 2 + singleMoto;

        if (children > childSeats)
        {
            return false;
        }

        adultSeats -= children;

        return adults == adultSeats;
    }
```

Outputs:

```
Validate(3,0,2,1) -- false
Validate(5,1,4,1) -- true
Validate(2,1,3,0) -- false
```

Comment: The first statement should be false according to question.

Comment: @venerik: Ah, so it should. Changed the final return statement. Now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(child <= doubleMoto && (child + 2*(doubleMoto-child) + singleMoto == adults))
   {
     //...
   }
```

Every child requires one doubleMoto. 1 adult per doubleMoto with child, 1 for the other doubleMoto's, 1 for each singleMoto.

Edit:
 'child' must be <= doubleMoto. This is the only way they can be transported.
 The remaining seats must be filled by adults.

On the double-motorcycles, 1 adults must accompany each child. For the motorcycles without any children (doubleMoto - child), there are 2 adults each. For each singleMoto, only 1 adult rides.

Hence, `child + 2*(doubleMoto-child) + singleMoto == adults`